# Geb click executed before input is completed

Tags: grails, geb

I'm running a simple Geb test like so:

```
class IndexPage extends Page {
  //static url = "http://localhost:8080/sampleGrailsApp"
  static at = { title == "sampleGrailsApp" }
  static content = {
    signInButton { $("div", 0, class: "container-fluid").find("button", 0) }
    modalFooterSignInButton(wait: true, to: MyPage) { $("footer", 0, class: "modal-footer").find("input", 0, class: "btn-primary") }
    modalFooterUsernameInput { $("form").username = it }
    modalFooterPasswordInput { $("form").password = it }
    signIn { username, password ->
      signInButton.click()
      waitFor { modalFooterSignInButton.present }
      modalFooterUsernameInput username
      modalFooterPasswordInput password
      modalFooterSignInButton.click()
    }
  }    
}
```

In my test, the page is called as follows:

```
def "sigin"() {
    given: "User is at index page"
    at IndexPage

    when: "User signs in"
    signIn "username","password"

    then: "Goes to MyPage"
    at MyPage
  }
```

On some occasions, the modalFooterSignInButton.click() happens before the username has been  entered completely therefore failing the test. Has anyone encountered this before? How do I wait for input to complete first before click is activated? I'm using Geb 0.9.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `isDisplayed()` instead of present as present means is present in the code but isDisplayed() means it appears in the UI. Hope the following stuffs would solve your problem!

```
waitFor { modalFooterSignInButton.isDisplayed()}
```

Also, use `waitFor{}` in case of critical situations as I don't know anything about your app.

Comment: Thanks. isDisplayed() seems to have resolved the issue. I can't be certain at this point in time because the issue was intermittent. But I've run the test a few times and have not encountered the issue. Thanks once again.

Comment: @user3240644: No worries, man! Feeling really awesome that it worked for you! Let's grow the geb community and make it a bigger one!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like :

```
waitFor { $(<username-input>).text().contains("username") } // after username is entered.
waitFor { $(<password-input>).text().contains("password") } // after password is entered.
```

before calling modalFooterSignInButton.click()

Also, is this behavior specific to any browser or it happens in all the browsers?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it doesn't work. I do not think that its possible to read the text input since it does not appear in the html. I'm currently testing it only in Chrome so I'm not sure if it happens in other browsers.

Comment: Not an ideal solution but if you add a sleep(500) or sleep(1000) before modalFooterSignInButton.click() then it should work.

Comment: I've never seen anyone out there having to wait for text input to complete so this behaviour baffles me. :(

Comment: waitFor should be good enough to handle this kind of situations! Even Erdi or Peter who are the core developer of geb, they always discourage to use sleep or related things! I myself never used sleep in geb!

Comment: @user3240644 Even I have not encountered this behavior but I had always used FireFox for my testing. Mamun : Agree with you but exceptions are always there :)

Comment: @LalitAgarwal: True but not specifically with sleep in geb. I can remember one exception that was working with browser specific conditions. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun Correct me if I'm wrong but waitFor won't work for this case since Geb is unable to read what was typed into the input box right?

Comment: It should throw an exception. Can you try with isDisplayed() as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: @user3240644 Also can you check if there is any update available for the chrome driver you are using? As chrome keeps on updating in background sometimes these issues are solved by updating the driver. If possible try this with Firefox as well.

Comment: Lalit, thanks for your help. @S.M.AlMamun's answer seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: @user3240644: Why don't you accept and upvote the answer, so that other would not ask the same/similar question in future? Cheers!